# UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def function():
    return "Hello Work"

print('here')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The `print` works, but the server does not start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here, courtesy of josechval. This worked for me. https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/257

Jose says: "You need to edit the "echo" function definition at ../site-packages/click/utils.py . The default value for the "file" parameter must be sys.stdout instead of None. Do the same for the "secho" function definition at ../site-packages/click/termui.py"

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `__name__ == '__main__'` and not `if name == 'main'`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue

There is a change that I made in the configuration file "Utils"
I commented a this part:

if message:
   write("Something Something")

I dont know the exact reason why is this happening, but yeah it surely worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved adding these two lines:

app.css.config.serve_locally = True

app.script.config.serve_locally = True

I should say that I had done both suggestions (changing echo and secho file and downgrading my flask to 0.12.2 but they had not been working for me)

Comment: if you find this answer useful please vote for it because stack overflow banned me for this answer !!!!!